# What is the difference between `position_dodge()` and `position_dodge2()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the difference between `position_dodge()` and `position_dodge2()` functions? When to use which one?

The help page says "Unlike `position_dodge()`, `position_dodge2()` works without a grouping variable in a layer" What does that mean?

Answer (score 5):

from github: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2767

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(bin = factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3)),
              type = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), 
              beta = c(10,20,30,40,50,60))

# Put "fill" in global aes() and dodging works in all layers
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = beta, fill = type)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge")  +
    geom_errorbar(aes( ymin = beta - 4, ymax = beta + 4),
                  position = position_dodge(width = .9) )
```

[image]

```
# Move "fill" to geom_bar() and geom_errorbar() doesn't dodge
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = beta)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = "dodge")  +
    geom_errorbar(aes( ymin = beta - 4, ymax = beta + 4),
                  position = position_dodge(width = .9) )
```

[image]

```
# But if use position_dodge2() all layers dodge
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = beta)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = "dodge2")  +
    geom_errorbar(aes( ymin = beta - 4, ymax = beta + 4),
                  position = position_dodge2(width = .9) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Create some data

To illustrate the difference, let's construct some data:

```r
# Example dataset
(dat <- data.frame(
    category = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
    value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
))
#   category value
# 1        A     1
# 2        A     2
# 3        A     3
# 4        B     4
# 5        B     5
# 6        B     6
```

And let's construct the barebones of a plot without a grouping variable (such as `color` or `fill` mapped to a plot aesthetic).

```r
g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = category, y = value)) +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 24)
```

#### `position_dodge()`

If we try to apply `position_dodge()` to this data, it does not actually dodge the bars. They are stacked on top of each other, each one unit taller than the previous one on the y-axis:

```r
g +
    geom_bar(
        stat = "identity",
        position = position_dodge(),
        color = "black",
        fill = NA
    )
```

[image]

#### `position_dodge2()`

Conversely, `position_dodge2()` understands the bars should appear side-by-side:

```r
g +
    geom_bar(
        stat = "identity",
        position = position_dodge2(padding = 0),
        color = "black",
        fill = NA
    )
```

[image]

#### Other differences

You might also noticed I provided `padding = 0`. That's because the `position_dodge2()` function takes two parameters, `padding` and `reverse`, that `position_dodge()` does not. These are set out in the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html). In those functions with a grouping variable, where you can use either, you need to set `position_dodge2(padding = 0)` to get identical output to `position_dodge()`.